# Using PHP SDK 4 how to get a list of user's of your web app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm disliking the facebook documentation of PHP SDK v4 (I've never used previous and starting out). I can't figure out how to get a list of user's of your web app. Can somebody help I'd really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't provide a way to retrieve users who have your application installed. This should be stored and tracked on your end when a new user installs the application.